# Refresh Angular component similar to Cron job

Tags: javascript, angular, cron

I have a Dashboard component in my Angular 6 application which I need to refresh every clock minute as the data that am fetching from API gets updated every minute (There is a Cron job running on backed to update the data).

I know about `Observable.interval(60000)` but it would be my last option to use as my API data gets refreshed after every minute in the clock and not on 60 sec interval.

For e.g. Say App starts at 8h 0 min and 30 sec AM. I don't want my dashboard to refresh after 60 sec i.e 8h 1 min and 30 sec but I want it to refresh on 8h 1 min and 0 sec. Hope what am asking for is clear.

Comment: Please explain what the difference is between "every minute on the clock" and  "60 sec interval"

Comment: It  means say my app starts at 8 h 0 min and 30 sec AM. I don't want my dashboard to refresh after 60 sec i.e 8h 1 min and 30 sec but I want it to refresh on 8h 1 min and 0 sec. Hope it makes clear.

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate the difference between current millisecond count and zero before setting up the Observable.

```js
...
const now = new Date();
const initialDelay = 60 * 1000 - (now.getSeconds() * 1000 + now.getMilliseconds());
Observable
  .timer(initialDelay, 60000)
  .subscribe(...)
```

Precision might not be ideal but maybe this will be enough.

**UPDATE**: using a WebSocket connection may be a more robust solution. I suppose backend app knows when data is updated so it can send new data right after new data becomes available. This way you have scheduling configured in one place.

Basically you would need a service that wraps socket connection and handles initalization and listening to messages from server. It would also provide an observable for subscribing to new messages.

Maybe [this article](https://medium.com/dailyjs/real-time-apps-with-typescript-integrating-web-sockets-node-angular-e2b57cbd1ec1) will be more helpful.

Comment: Thanks. That's how I accomplished it currently. But I wanted to keep the time easily configurable as in a Cron job so that can change config anytime to get it refreshed.